# How can I reuse a type of an interface member?

Tags: typescript

```
export interface Car {
    Name: string;
    Speed: number;
    Manufactured: number;
}

const Speed: Car.Speed = 200;
```

Currently, `Car.Speed` is causing an error:

> Cannot access 'Car.Speed' because 'Car' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'Speed' in 'Car' with 'Car["Speed"]'?

Comment: Car.Speed is nothing in itself. Javascript is not going to process it after compilation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can "query" the type of the member using following syntax:

```
const Speed: Car['Speed'] = 200;
```

More info on lookup types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

Comment: Is Car an object?

Comment: No, that's a type (interface)

Comment: @AlekseyL. - No, but that's not a property accessor, beacuse it's in a type expression, not a runtime expression: [Live demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20Car%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Speed%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Manufactured%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Speed%3A%20Car%5B'Speed'%5D%20%3D%20200%3B). Aleksey - Wow, that's really cool.

Comment: Car["speed"], I thought '[""]' syntax is reserved for object only (at least in javascript).

Comment: @Ajay - That's JavaScript. This is the type portion of the declaration, which is TypeScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is kind of mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) I'll try to find a place with better definition

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see also https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types