# How to access the type of a field of an object type using the dot notation

Tags: typescript

Given an object type, one can access the type of one of the fields using the bracket-string notation. Why isn’t it possible to use the dot notation as well, like in Javascript? Does it conflict with something else? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

```js
type Foo = {value: number | string};
type Bar = Foo["value"]; // Works, Bar is number | string
type Baz = Foo.value;    // Error
```

The error message says something about namespaces, but even if there is a namespace named `Foo`, then `Foo.value` refers to a value and not a type, so it still doesn’t seem ambiguous.

Comment: It is (kinda) covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607608/how-can-i-reuse-a-type-of-an-interface-member)  question if you havent read it ? But I think the sources they refer to is a bit lackluster. Would be interesting to know why the dot-notation is omitted in this case.

Comment: Dot notation is just not supported for types. It works only for namespaces

Comment: [Why You Can't Use Dot Notation On Types](https://www.totaltypescript.com/why-you-cant-use-dot-notation-on-types) from Matt Pocock provides a very good overview on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked myself that, when I first encountered this feature. The feature in question is called "[Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)" and if you look into the documentation it's clear why TypeScript chose this syntax over the dot notation: It is much flexible.
Consider these examples:

```js
type Person = { age: number; name: string; alive: boolean };
type I1 = Person["age" | "name"]; 
// I guess here we could do: type I1 = Person.age | Person.name; 

type I2 = Person[keyof Person];  
 
type AliveOrName = "alive" | "name";
type I3 = Person[AliveOrName];
```

As noted in the comment the first example could easily be rewritten with the dot notation, but the other examples are clearer with the array index notation.

Maybe TypeScript could add the suggested dot syntax for simple cases as syntactic sugar, but I'm not sure everyone would like this as then there are multiple notations for the same feature.

Comment: I know that there are situations where you need to use the bracket notation, I'm absolutely not suggesting to remove it. It's just in the cases where we have a given string (like "value") that it feels like we could allow both, just like property access in Javascript.

Comment: It is basically a language design decision. As I said, it could be added as an alternative syntax, but It could also be argued, that adding multiple ways to do the same thing is bloating the language. If you want it added to the TypeScript you could always open an Issue on Github or participate in community meetings and bring it up there.

Answer (score -2):

with the following code:

```
type Baz = Foo.value;
```

If you want to use it, you must define value of `value` variable.

Because, Object properties are equivalent to key-value pairs. **Property keys are either strings or symbols.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#properties

Comment: Are you sure about this? I get the same error when trying it in typescript sandbox